# For loop breaking IndexOf

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, indexof

Well I've ripped my hair off because I assumed I was finished this script but suddenly adding ONE more for loop broke every single indexOf, I tried to create checks so the console wouldn't freak out, but sadly no success. using a static value for "z" or LevelCheck allows for all the indexOfs to work properly but as soon as a for loop is involved, it seems none of the indexOfs wishes to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tempval = new Array();
function Renew(){ //Reset tempval back to val
    for(d=0;d<val.length;d++){
        tempval[d] = val[d];
    }
}
function UpdateLoop(){
    Renew();
    var Levels = document.getElementById("Lvl");
    if(Levels){
        for(z=0; z<=Levels.value; z++){
            Update(z);
        }
    }
}
function Update(LevelCheck){
    for (i=0; i<=key.length; i++){
        if(key[i] != null){
            if ( key[i].indexOf("rate") > -1 ) { //Search through
                for (r=0; r<=key.length; r++){
                    if(key[i].indexOf(key[r]) > -1){ //Finds out which form it should replace
                        var raw=tempval[i];
                        for (y=0; y<=key.length; y++){
                            if(key[i] != "movespeed" && key[i] != "Movrate"){ //add a check to see if string is not there
                                var item = document.getElementById(key[y]);
                                if (item) {    //Make it use formula value and then put that result into a value and loop back into function until level reached. If level changed to a lower number, reset to original value and repeat
                                    //raw=raw.replace(key[y],document.getElementById(key[y]).value); //replace this with val[y]
                                    raw=raw.replace(key[y],tempval[y]);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                                break;
                        }
                        if(raw != null){
                            if(raw.indexOf("Mov") > -1){
                                for(x=0; x<=key.length; x++){
                                    if(key[x].indexOf("movespeed") > -1){
                                        //raw=raw.replace("Mov",document.getElementById(key[x]).value);
                                        raw=raw.replace("Mov",tempval[x]);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(raw.indexOf("Lvl") > -1){
                                raw=raw.replace("Lvl",document.getElementById('Lvl').value);
                            }
                            if(raw.indexOf("Exp") > -1){
                                raw=raw.replace("Exp","0");
                            }
                        }
                        if( document.getElementById('Lvl').value == LevelCheck){
                            alert("Input:"+tempval[i]);
                            if(key[i] == "Movrate"){
                                document.getElementById("movespeed").value = eval(raw);
                            }
                            else{
                                var check = document.getElementById(key[r]);
                                if (check){
                                    document.getElementById(key[r]).value = eval(raw);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            tempval[r] = eval(raw);
                        }
                        break; //So it doesn't keep searching
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Html portion(This is generated via php so I just used what the browser generated)

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Creature Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="Text" name="CName" value="Thing" size="10%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Level:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="Text" id="Lvl" name="level" onchange="" value="1" size="10%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>movespeed:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="Text" name="movespeed" id="movespeed" value="1" size="10%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>str:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="Text" name="str" id="str" value="4" size="10%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dex:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="Text" name="dex" id="dex" value="3" size="10%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>int:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="Text" name="int" id="int" value="1" size="10%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>will:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="Text" name="will" id="will" value="2" size="10%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var key=new Array();
            var val=new Array();
            key.push("movespeed");
            val.push("1");
            key.push("str");
            val.push("4");
            key.push("dex");
            val.push("3");
            key.push("int");
            val.push("1");
            key.push("will");
            val.push("2");
            key.push("Movrate");
            val.push("Mov+1");
            key.push("strrate");
            val.push("1+str");
            key.push("dexrate");
            val.push("1+dex+(str/4)");
            key.push("intrate");
            val.push("1+int");
            key.push("willrate");
            val.push("1+will");
        </script>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" name="button" value="Use Formula" onclick="UpdateLoop();">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Save">
            </td>
```

Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 2 has no method 'indexOf' Monsters.php:62
Update Monsters.php:62
UpdateLoop Monsters.php:39
onclick Monsters.php:28
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. Dude, you definitely need to rethink your code. You can't go crazy for code like that.

Comment: could you align your HTML? It also looks incomplete.

Comment: Which is the 62nd line of the generated page? And what's the content of `key`, `val` and `tempval`?

Comment: for if if for if for if if } } } } } } - the cost to transform it in human thought is too high

Comment: I could not make myself to read all of your code but i can say as I heard sometimes the indexOf method works buggy. I use jQuery's $.indexOf() instead.

Comment: @user1600680  my mistake. I mean $.inArray() and I mean it of the indexOf buggyness.

Comment: @user1600680 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/About?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FAbout#JavaScript_versions

Comment: @user1600680 You could google it by yourself :) http://soledadpenades.com/2007/05/17/arrayindexof-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: @user1600680 I never say a word bug I said buggy... These are diffrent words as I know even with my insufficent language skills. And as I wrote "as I heard" I didn't for sure of it. Well if I were sure I would'nt write it to the commets. I would just answer. And I'm sure now if a part of a code wont work on a browser it means its buggy. (thats the definitaion of bugginess)  And a last side note you are a rude man.

Comment: Well removing the forloop as I said fixed it apparently. Basically what I'm trying to do is replace strings with numbers but the strings will NEVER or rarely be the same with the exception of Mov,Lvl and Exp..also the actual placement of the strings will never been or rarely be on the same spot so after replacing all the strings with the initial values it's supposed to evaluate the number  and then continue until the designated "level" is reached, and if the designated level is lower than what the values should be it restarts and redoes it until the level is proper

Comment: What user1600680 said, my issue still remains unsolved despite the mini war happening here

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your Update function to the following:

```
function UpdateLoop(){
    var Levels = document.getElementById("Lvl");
    if(Levels){
        for(z=0; z<=Levels.value; z++){
            Renew();
            Update(z);
        }
    }
}
```

After processing Level 0, the `tempval` array had the values from Level 0, which wiped out the original values from the `val` array.

Making this change fixed the problem in my tests: http://jsfiddle.net/jimmym715/xTUND/

oh, and what MaxArt said in the comments above is right on the money... there are far better ways to accomplish what you're going for here

Comment: It does somewhat give me a better idea of why the script isn't working but why exactly is the val, values being wiped out in the first place?

Comment: The values in `val` *aren't* wiped out, which is why we're able to refresh the values in `tempval` after each level.  However, the values in `tempval` are reset explicitly at the end of the `r` loop if the value of `LevelCheck` doesn't match the value in the `Lvl` textbox. Thus, when running `Update` for Level 0, the values in `tempval` are overwritten, and this, in turn, requires that the values in `tempval` be reset for `Update` to work on the next Level (though running `Update` on Level 0 would be unnecessary if you're not going to keep the values, so I'm guessing that something is amiss)

Comment: Well It turns out that something similar to what you are stating had happened, the values were only numbers so they were not getting parsed correct, in order to remedy the situation an .toString() had to be placed to cast each int back into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that flat numbers are NOT strings so in order to safely go through every value .toString() had to be present, thanks everyone for trying though.
so it would look like:

```
key[i].toString().indexOf(key[r])
```